# Why does conda install pip/setuptools etc...?

Tags: python, conda

I am using conda to create clean environments for each my my python projects.  I'd like to bootstrap the environmetn with only python, and not muddy it up wtih dependencies that aren't necessary.  I noticed that when creating a barebones venv with anaconda:

```
conda create --name myenv python
```

It must install the following new packages,

```
certifi:        2017.11.5-py36hb8ac631_0
pip:            9.0.1-py36h226ae91_4
python:         3.6.3-h3b118a2_4
setuptools:     36.5.0-py36h65f9e6e_0
vc:             14-h2379b0c_2
vs2015_runtime: 14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_2
wheel:          0.30.0-py36h6c3ec14_1
wincertstore:   0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
```

Does conda *require* these in some sense to operate?  Can they be kept out of the installation if one only plans to use the python standard library?

Comment: Right, but I"d like to use anaconda to keep this in a nicely contained virtual environment so I cans witch too and fro with the conda CLI.  Manually installing a python version just seems like trouble.

Comment: I am not familiar with how conda works. But according to the list of commands, you could try to `--no-deps` (Do not install dependencies.) or `--no-default-packages` (Ignore create_default_packages in the .condarc file.), but I am not sure if this includes the packages you are talking about. Might be worth a try. I guess these packages are included because they are used almost every single time. Reference: https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html

Comment: If you're going pure vanilla, [Pyenv will make you Pythons](https://askubuntu.com/a/865644/140640)  directly from the source.

Comment: Thanks @NickT  I'd still prefer not go full vanilla simply because I like commands like conda env list to remind me where all my virtual envs are and stuff.

Comment: pyenv has similar facilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then don't run them. The point of these dependencies are that you can't extend your environment with any third party libraries unless they are present, and most projects do depend on some third party libraries (or that your own library should be installable) - so they're installed by default, since they're usually required and useful.

You can ask the conda venv create script to not include any default packages with `--no-default-packages` and `--no-deps`. The official virtualenv package supports `--no-pip`, `--no-setuptools` and `--no-wheel` to skip them.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for